# How to get Users start and end location in Uber

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, uber-api

I am developing a customized App for Android and iOS. In the current UBER app, a user can share his/her location with friends and family, and a google map link is shared to the user in return they can then follow the Uber rider. I want to add this function to my app, however i want to eliminate the manual process, of how it works in the Uber app.
My App is a family care app, where the user will add 3 guardians, and once the user sits in his / her Uber, Guardians can automatically start tracking the users location, start trip, end trip etc..

Can someone point these things out and show a link or reference that detail what I am requesting and how to integrate these features into our App?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Uber provides webhooks for this: https://developer.uber.com/docs/trip-experiences/introduction

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you for your message, however in the above case we will have to integrate the whole UBER SDK which will include booking an Uber through our app to track the users location. I just want to be able to track the users location once he / she sits in an uber and in enroute from Point A to Point B

Comment: Yeah, not sure that's possible without their SDK.